# Load dynamic content using jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jquery load() can be used to load components from another page.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

But if the `#container` contain some elements which load dynamically, the load() function does not render those dynamic components inside `#result` element.

Ex: A customer review page load user comments dynamically. Therefore, the comments cannot be shown inside `#result` element.

Is it possible to use `load()` function to achieve this or is there any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: Just give a comment before down vote pls

Comment: 1. Get the page content. 2. Get the `target-div` element by Id from that content. 3. insert that into the desired place.

Comment: @ICE Thanks for the comment. I already did that. But it only loads the static content. As I explained in the question, it does not load dynamic content. (Content of customer reviews in my scenario)

Comment: @Choxmi I think it's impossible due to you can not know when the dynamic load finished,unless you have related event method to call

Comment: @lucumt  Yes it seems to be impossible. I tried Ajax load as well. Even that did not work for me. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.
Source taken from `.load()` documentation - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @LajosArpad `Failed to load javascript:void(0): Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https` this was the error message I got

Answer (score 2):

One issue you're hitting is down to this part of your question:

> the source page has some elements which loads dynamically

Once you've worked around CORS and its ilk, all you are doing is still asking the remote server for a static file and rendering that.

However, on the source site you will almost certainly find additional scripts that populate those elements; those scripts run on the source server, but will not be executed by your current code. You would need to replicate the execution of these scripts on your own site, including pulling additional data across.

An easier solution would be to ask the owner of the source site if they have an externally-available API, which will allow you to pull this data across and render it automatically.

Comment: API is the best solution for cross origin, because if they change the element id or structure, it can make undesired result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Adrian.Since  I'm using a plugin for the source page and I don't have any contact to the plugin owner. :(

Comment: @Choxmi if you can not create the API or ask for API, the only solution for you is the thing that I offered. You should get it on your server not on the client side.

Comment: @ICE thanks. Yes that seems to be the only option I have. :(

Comment: @Choxmi If you can work out the calls the source site makes, and *if it doesn't breach their terms & conditions* (check first), you could consider writing your own API (avoiding CORS problems completely) and calling that from your site.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Thanks for the guidance. I'll try that way

Answer (score 1):

On PHP, for cross origin you can get element like this:

```
//url
$url = 'https://url.com'; 

//get content from the URL
$cotnent = file_get_contents($url);

//disable errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

//Load HTML
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML($cotnent);

//Get the ID that you want
$elm = $dochtml->getElementById('elementid');

if ($elm){
    //elm content
    echo $elm->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `iframe` otherwise you need to have the administration to those websites because you will need to edit 
`.htaccess` and make `allow-access`

Comment: iframe will give you the same cross origin problem, if you want to fetch the element from it.